# changing GAE db.Model schema on dev_server with ListProperties? BadValueError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My understanding of changing db.Model schemas is that it 'doesn't matter' if you add a property and then try and fetch old entities without that property.

Indeed, adding the following property to my `SiteUser` db.Model running on dev_server:

`category_subscriptions = db.StringProperty()`

Still allows me to retrieve an old SiteUser entity doesn't have this property (via a GQL query).

However, changing the property to a list property, (either StringListProperty, ListProperty):

`category_subscriptions = db.StringListProperty()`

results in the following error when I try and retrieve the user:

`BadValueError: Property category_subscriptions is required`

This is on the SDK dev server version 1.7.4. Why is that and how would I work around it?

Comment: this is ONLY a problem on dev_server. in production it's fine.

Comment: Could you try retrieving an old `SiteUser` entity using its `Key`  id instead of a GQL query and see if you still get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's my workaround to get it working on dev_server:

1) update your model in production and deploy it

2) use `appcfg.py download_data` and grab all entities of the type you've updated

3) use `appcfg.py upload_data` and push all the entities into your local datastore

voila.. your local datastore entities can now be retrieved without generating `BadValueError`